# print values from function

Tags: r

I am searching for a way in R to get the all numbers for integers from a function in a range from `a` to `b`

```
pfA <- function(x) {  return (  123 * x ) ; }
p_a = Vectorize(pfA, "x")
plot(0,0, col="purple", type="l", xlim=c(-5,5000), ylim=c(-5,5000))
curve (p_a(x), col="red", add=TRUE)
print_values((p_a(x),a,b)
```

where print_values would return a list (or two dimesional array), containing all `x` in the range `a` to `b` and the corresponding return value of the function

```
 1 : 123
 2 : 246
 3 : 369
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the code of the `curve` function to create `myfun`.

```
myfun <-
function (expr, from, to) 
{
  sexpr <- substitute(expr)
  x <- seq.int(from, to)
  ll <- list(x = x)
  y <- eval(sexpr, envir = ll)
  cbind(x = ll[["x"]], y)
}
```

Example usage:

```
a <- -5
b <- 5
myfun(p_a(x), a, b)

#        x    y
#  [1,] -5 -615
#  [2,] -4 -492
#  [3,] -3 -369
#  [4,] -2 -246
#  [5,] -1 -123
#  [6,]  0    0
#  [7,]  1  123
#  [8,]  2  246
#  [9,]  3  369
# [10,]  4  492
# [11,]  5  615
```